Week of month sequence - reset every 4th Monday across years
A similar question to this resolved post I raised.
Week of month sequence across years
I want to create a sequence of week numbers across a list of dates, but have the sequence reset on the 4th Monday of each month.
Example below with the result I am hoping to achieve:


If you ignore all the 5th Mondays, by December you will reset to 1 in the middle of the month.

Indeed, taking the dates you have and resetting at 4 each week, the Full last week in June is week 1.  With 1/7/2024, a Monday, being the start of week 2

Yes that is actually the intention.

then =MOD(INT((A2-DATE(2024,4,1))/7),4)+1 where the DATE() is an arbitrary Monday where you want it to be the start of week 1

ah that's clever! Thank you very much Scott.
